# Pulsar `atom-ide-ui` package

Tags: atom-editor, pulsar-editor

I'm having the `atom-ide-ui` package throwing errors and sometimes not working as expected. I mean the UI elements.

Is there a new updated replacement for it? Couldn't find anything on github and searching also didn't give me any relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is the `atom-ide-base` package.